# What is the way to draw custom images on MCP 1.16.5?

Tags: java, minecraft

I was trying to draw a background for my main menu. This process can be simply done in Minecraft 1.8 by placing the image inside mc's assets folder and binding the resource using its path. However, after moving to MCP 1.16.5, this method can't be done the same way anymore. I tried researching articles but found nothing useful.

This is my code, it's put in the `render()` method

```
minecraft.getTextureManager().bindTexture(new ResourceLocation("mindblown", "mindblown/background.png"));
blit(matrixStack, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

I also put my background.png file in the following directory

```
src/main/resources/minecraft/assets/mindblown
```

Upon executing the code, MC threw this `FileNotFoundException`

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: mindblown:mindblown/background.png
    at net.minecraft.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:69) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.SimpleTexture$TextureData.getTextureData(SimpleTexture.java:112) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.SimpleTexture.getTextureData(SimpleTexture.java:84) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.SimpleTexture.loadTexture(SimpleTexture.java:34) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_230183_b_(TextureManager.java:134) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTexture(TextureManager.java:95) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.bindTextureRaw(TextureManager.java:77) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.bindTexture(TextureManager.java:61) [classes/:?]
    at mindblown.gui.main.Main.render(Main.java:20) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.ResourceLoadProgressGui.render(ResourceLoadProgressGui.java:82) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.GameRenderer.updateCameraAndRender(GameRenderer.java:746) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1047) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:564) [classes/:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:215) [classes/:?]
    at mcp.client.Start.main(Start.java:17) [classes/:?]
```

Nothing showed up but a yellow and black picture after I try to use `blit()`, meaning the texture wasn't bound correctly.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPbi1.png)

Noticing there is nothing else but 4 folders, including my `mindblown` folder, I think I might have put the image in the incorrect directory. However, I am unable to find any file that is used in MC code. For example:

*From RealmsMainScreen.java - line 55*

```
private static final ResourceLocation field_237542_p_ = new ResourceLocation("realms", "textures/gui/realms/expired_icon.png");
```

This is later bound in line 1120, and drawn successfully without throwing any error.

```
this.minecraft.getTextureManager().bindTexture(field_237542_p_);
RenderSystem.color4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
AbstractGui.blit(p_237614_1_, p_237614_2_, p_237614_3_, 0.0F, 0.0F, 10, 28, 10, 28);
```

Now, the weird thing is, I tried to search for `expired_icon.png` in `src` and it returned nothing, meaning the texture must have been stored inside a compressed file (which I assume Windows doesn't scan its contents). My questions is: **Where do I put my image to make Minecraft recognize it?**

I appreciate any help or information

Answer (score 0):

put it into src/main/resources/assets/minecraft